# Need to update a text from a widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, setstate, scaffold

I'm trying to update with SetState but it doesn't update the elements so i have to close the widget and open to update the text.

What this code do, is that when you open a widget like an alert dialog you press a button to set up a date, and then when you set up the date it will apear there, but if you cancel the date is the actual date, so DateTime.now() but when i press ok, SetState doesn't refresh my text

```
**Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Future<void> _showDialog() async {
  String? ex1;
  String? ex2;
  UserModel? ex3;
  UserModel? ex4;
  List<String> ex5 = [];
  String? ex6;
  final ex6Controller = TextEditingController(text: "20");
  final modelItems = List.generate(
    50,
    (index) => UserModel(
      avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/lTy4hiN.jpg",
      name: "Deivão $index",
      id: "$index",
      createdAt: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  );
  slidedialog.showSlideDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Select Date'),
            onPressed: () async {
              DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: date,
                firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                lastDate: DateTime(2100),
              );
              if (newDate == null) return;
              //Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              // Navigator.pop(context, true);
              setState(() => date = newDate);
            },
          ),
          
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(ex3?.name ?? "Item Builder Example"),
            onPressed: () {
              SelectDialog.showModal<UserModel>(
                context,
                label: "Item Builder Example",
                items: modelItems,
                selectedValue: ex3,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, UserModel item,
                    bool isSelected) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: !isSelected
                        ? null
                        : BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: item.avatar == null
                              ? null
                              : NetworkImage(item.avatar!)),
                      selected: isSelected,
                      title: Text(item.name),
                      subtitle: Text(item.createdAt.toString()),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                onChange: (selected) {
                  setState(() {
                    ex3 = selected;
                  });
                },[enter image description here][1]
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ));
}
```

The problem is in this line, this SetState doesn't refresh the text. I have to close the widget "works like alertdialog" and open again to refresh the text

```
slidedialog.showSlideDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        '${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 16),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Select Date'),
        onPressed: () async {
          DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: date,
            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
            lastDate: DateTime(2100),
          );
          if (newDate == null) return;
          //Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
          // Navigator.pop(context, true);
          setState(() => date = newDate);
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap column with `StatefulBuilder`. There you will get function `setState`.

```
slidedialog.showSlideDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
  child: StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (context, _setState){
      return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Select Date'),
          onPressed: () async {
            DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: date,
              firstDate: DateTime(2000),
              lastDate: DateTime(2100),
            );
            if (newDate == null) return;
            //Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            // Navigator.pop(context, true);
            _setState(() => date = newDate);
          },
        ),
      ),
     }
  )
);
```